# Python Celery socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am using Celery 3.0 and have the configuration file like below.

celeryconfig.py

```
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 300
```

tasks.py

```
import celery

@celery.task
def function(x,y):
    return x + y
```

and function.py

```
from tasks import function

print function.delay(4,4).get()
```

I run the application with following command

```
celeryd --loglevel=INFO --config=celeryconfig
```

Everything is working great till now. I have redis and celery running and getting answers.

But when I run the function command from another file called parallelizer,

I get the socket error,

```
 socket.error: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

My file is like below,

```
from examples.dummy.tasks import function
print function.delay(4,4).get()
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: have you installed redis package along with redis-server on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was,

I was running celeryconfig.py under from a different path than my parallelizer.

When I carried the celeryconfig.py to same path with paralellizer it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and the issue was that I missed this code in my project's __init__.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

I hope it will be useful to someone out there...

Answer (score 7):

Had the same problem, ended up realizing that `rabbitmq` and `redis` processes were stoped.

On mac, if those services were installed via homebrew, then you can verify whether those services are running by running following command on terminal,

```
brew services list
```

can restart services by, (if installed via `brew`)

```
brew services restart rabbitmq
brew services restart redis
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue , and tried almost every solution from opensource , at the end i got solution which works 100% efficiently.

all you need to do is

inside

> projects--->>**init**.py

file
you have to add this two lines of code

> code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app
```

#Django #celery #redis #celeryconnectionerror #connectionrefused